# Dynamic getter method creation

Tags: java

I have created dynamic setter getter using Reflection API but it is creating performance issue so I want to replace my reflection code with some dynamic cutom method specially for getter.

I am planning to store all my field name in map but not sure how will I link my accurate values agains those fields.

I have tried with PropertyUtils as well but it also use reflection internally.

In the case of reflection it was working fine.
Is there any way to write dynamic getter value with fieldname verified because if i will store fields name in map on first attempt as key and value as null then how will i link specific value for that field after that and again it will be lengthy process.

Comment: Why do you need that read to be dynamic? Is it because you don't know the field names or getter names at compile time?

Comment: Anything that uses an arbitrary `String` provided at runtime to access a field or method by name is necessarily going to use reflection.  That encompasses pretty much everything I anticipate you meaning by "dynamic".  What's wrong with just writing and using ordinary getters and setters?

Comment: Alternatively, what's wrong with using one `Map` instead of separate fields?

Comment: I have all the details ready in my POJO class but we are working on java side performance and due to reflection we are facing issue. But if I have 50 or more fields in my pojo then i will have to write that much set and get statement for that everytime instead of that i can make it dynamic to handle it internally without reflection.

Comment: You don't have to write getters and setters. Just find the "Generate getters and setters" functionality in your IDE and let that handle the boilerplate (or start using Kotlin).

Comment: Or use Lombok for that .....

Comment: Thanks Kayaman, I have idea about all these things gor pojo like getter setter creation through ide, reflection API, map creation for the same but here I have to replace my existing reflection code which  I have written earlier so I can not make big change her due to oroject impact si looking fir the replacement way for reflection get method .

Comment: It's your own fault for writing that reflection code. A lesson learned for your next project, right?

Comment: Yes true but it was suggested and decided in design phase only amd I was not aware about ihe performance problem in reflection but now I gaining knowledge in the same. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use Lombok for that https://projectlombok.org/. It will generate boilerplate getter/setters for you on precompile.

it will be like

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class LombokExample(){
   private String myField;
}
```

done - end of class definition - no getters/setters required
 and still you will be able to

```
lombok=new LombokExample();
lombok.getMyField();
lombok.setMyField();
```